# Accessing Google App Engine data with Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to access my Google App Engine app's data using Google Cloud Datastore. I followed the steps from [here](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/activate) from the section entitled "Google Cloud Datastore for an Existing App Engine Application". Once I got my GCE VM up, I tried to read from my application but got the stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "datastore_test.py", line 30, in <module>
    get()
  File "datastore_test.py", line 21, in get
    resp = datastore.lookup(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googledatastore-v1beta1_rev1_1.0.0-py2.7.egg/googledatastore/__init__.py", line 66, in lookup
    return get_default_connection().lookup(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googledatastore-v1beta1_rev1_1.0.0-py2.7.egg/googledatastore/connection.py", line 82, in lookup
    datastore_v1_pb2.LookupResponse)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googledatastore-v1beta1_rev1_1.0.0-py2.7.egg/googledatastore/connection.py", line 207, in _call_method
    raise RPCError(method, response, content)
googledatastore.connection.RPCError: lookup RPC client failure with HTTP(403) Forbidden: Access Not Configured
```

How can I configure access to my data?

Comment: Can you make sure you enabled the Google Cloud Datastore API in http://cloud.google.com/console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As proppy mentioned, I had to enable the API from https://cloud.google.com/console. Now it works as expected.

Comment: Note that you should enable it from http://cloud.google.com/console, not code.google.com/apis/console